# diagonal elements of an orthogonal positive definite matrix constitutes a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A=[a_{ij}]$ for $1\le i,j \le n^2$ be an orthogonal positive definite matrix 
then $B=[b_{ij}]$ for $1\le i,j \le n$ such that $b_{ij}=a_{n(i-1)+j,n(i-1)+j}$ is also positive definite.

Comment: It's not a homework site where you post question without showing your efforts.

Comment: @mathlover I would have if I could have

Comment: Two remarks: 1) Is there a reason for choosing $A$ to be a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix ? (instead of being plainly $n \times n$) ? 2) A positive definite matrix that is as well orthogonal  has very specific properties ; in particular, its singular values, which are known to be the eigenvalues of $A^TA=I$ are all equal to 1...

Comment: @JeanMarie 1) I wanted $B$ to be a square matrix 2) does it help??

Comment: For point 1) I understand now. For point 2) I am not sure it helps but knowing that all singular values are 1 is a striking property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive definite, there is some orthogonal $U$ such that
$\Lambda = U^T A U$ is diagonal. Since $A$ is positive definite, all elements 
of $\Lambda$ are strictly positive. Since $A^TA = I$, we see that $\Lambda^2 = I$, hence all elements are $\pm 1$, and hence all elements are exactly $1$
and so $A=I$.

Hence $B = e e^T$, where $e= (1,...,1)^T$ and hence $B \ge 0$. However,
$B$ is not positive definite.